# Get Postgres-activerecord setup to work both locally and in Heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, activerecord, heroku

I'm automating DB creation (with a Rakefile in a Sinatra App).

I would like to be able to run the rakefile from my Linux user "pete" (eg pete@pete_laptop: /path $ rake db:create) AND from Heroku.

It comes down to the settings in my config/database.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
  :host     => db.host,
  :port     => db.port,

  # pete@ubuntu_14.04_laptop--------
  # :username => 'pete',
  # :password => 'password',
  # OR
  # heroku -----------------
  # :username => db.user,
  # :password => db.password,

  :database => DB_NAME,
  :encoding => 'utf8'
)
```

If I use the pete@ubuntu_laptop settings, the database works in localhost but not in Heroku,
If I use the heroku settings, the database works in localhost but not in Heroku.

How can I setup this file/my ubuntu laptop so that the app works both on localhost & in Heroku?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables which can be accessed like `ENV["PG_USER"]` in Ruby. If you want to use it in a yml file you can put it in erb tags `<%= ENV["PG_USER"] %>` and render it with erb before passing it to your config.

You can set environment variables in your `.bashrc` or you can use something like the dotenv gem.  On heroku you can set environment variables like `heroku config:set PG_USER=postgres`.

But check whether this is really necessary for heroku. In Rails, for instance, heroku provides a database configuration, so there is no need to configure it.

Comment: thanks jphager2! that was exactly how I got it working in the end!

Answer (score 0):

oK! With help got it working!
used:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
  :host     => db.host,
  :port     => db.port,

  :username => ENV['PG_USER'] || db.user,
  :password => ENV['PG_PASSWORD'] || db.password,

  :database => DB_NAME,
  :encoding => 'utf8'
)
```

AND

added this to my shell-rc (in my case ~/.zshrc)

```
export PG_USER='pete'
export PG_PASSWORD='password'
```

now in my local environment the username & password pick up the ENV['PG...] variables from the terminal I launch the app in.

Note: 'export' is important - without it the variables don't get sent to the app's 'ENV'